# Is is possible to disallow all child directories in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I've recently set up my robots.txt file.

Nothing special - I have an asp.net site, so in addition to my pages, web.config etc. in the root directory, there are links to `/bin/` and some custom folders which are there for organisation rather than site structure.

At the moment I'm disallowing each directory individually, but I was wondering if it's possible to disallow all child directories from the root in one go.

I've taken a look at the documentation but not found the answer I want just yet - often it's not there because it's not possible.

Anyone advise as to whether this is do-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with wildcards:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/
```

Be aware that wildcards are an extension, and are not part of the original robots.txt standard. They are supported by all major search engines, but they are not supported by many special-purpose crawlers.

If you only care about major search engines, and you need to block hundreds or thousands of directories, then wildcards are a good solution. If you only need to block a handful of directories, then you are better off listing them individually.